# How can I call a playbook from a role?

Tags: ansible

I have a playbook which does a set of tasks, import a playbook and then perform next set of tasks in below order and it works well .

```yaml
---
- hosts: all
  tasks: 
    - include_tasks: task1.yml
    - include_tasks: tas2.yml
- import_playbook: play.yml
    - include_tasks: task3.yml
    - include_tasks: task4.yml
```

I am now planning to create a single role to incorporate this. Any suggestions how to add import_playbook in roles ?

Comment: What hosts should be active in this imported playbook? In other words, how would you like to combine the hosts from the play running the role and the hosts from the imported playbook?

Comment: Its used along with packer which creates an instance and perform the actions

Comment: It's not possible. There might be a solution if you provide [mre].

Comment: `import_playbook` is a playbook level verb. In a role, your write task files, not playbooks. Hence you cannot use that verb (you're already too high in the execution hierarchy).

Answer (score 0):

Convert *play.yml* to a role. For example, given the play

```yaml
shell> cat play.yml
- hosts: all

  tasks:

    - debug:
        msg: task 2
    - debug:
        msg: task 3
```

create the role *play*

```yaml
shell> cat roles/play/tasks/main.yml 
- debug:
    msg: task 2
- debug:
    msg: task 3
```

Then use the role in both plays

```yaml
shell> cat play.yml
- hosts: all

  roles:
    - play
```

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml
- hosts: all

  tasks:

    - debug:
        msg: task 1

    - import_role: play

    - debug:
        msg: task 4
```